# Pass array of objects to java web service

Tags: java, arrays, web-services, axis

I am not succeeding in passing an array of objects to a Java web service using Axis 1.4 1855 (according to the axis.jar manifest.mf file). I am using the IntelliJ IDE to help me build this, generate the WSDL, and generate the stubs.

A couple of weeks ago, I successfully created a very small web service that accepts a simple request object (RequObj, which aggregates a few Strings, ints, and doubles) and returning a simple response object (RespObj, also containing Strings, ints, and doubles). This is working fine.

But when I try to make a change to pass an array of the RequObj to the service instead of a single RequObj, I get an error:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:JO007BI-BOU7
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
```

... etc

The classes I am sending/receiving to/from the server are very basic. I get exactly the same error when I reduce both the RequObj and RespObj to just a single String member variable (m_reqString1 and m_resString1). I have regenerated the WSDL in the server, and in the client I regenerated the Java stubs (and apparently also the request and response class files) from the server WSDL file. I am obviously not a WSDL expert, but the WSDL seems to have the right stuff in it for passing an array of objects. I have also attached the WSDL for the case where the request and response objects ONLY contain a string.

I am really stuck and have had no luck investigating this on the various forums. I have seen many of the articles you have written, but none seem to address this specific issue… If I can't fix this, I will have to go back to calling my own Java DOM functions to turn my request/responses into XML, which I know is non-standard…

These are the classes that contain my request and response definitions. In the files I have attached, I have simplified these even more so that they ONLY contain just the single m_reqString1 and m_resString1, and I get the same error in that even simpler case.

```
public class RequObj  implements java.io.Serializable {
    public java.lang.String m_reqString1;
    public int m_reqInt1;
    public double m_reqDouble1;
    public java.lang.String m_reqString2;
    public int m_reqInt2;
    public double m_reqDouble2;
    public java.lang.String m_reqString3;
    public int m_reqInt3;
    public double m_reqDouble3;
    ...
}

public class RespObj  implements java.io.Serializable {
    public java.lang.String m_resString1;
    public int m_resInt1;
    public double m_resDouble1;
    public java.lang.String m_resString2;
    public int m_resInt2;
    public double m_resDouble2;
    public java.lang.String m_resString3;
    public int m_resInt3;
    public double m_resDouble3;
    ...
}
```

I can include any source files (such as the WSDL, client code, service code, stub code, etc) if that would help (I'm sure it would), but I mostly want to pose the question first. If someone would like to see this level of detail, I will put it up here with my question. Thanks very much -

Comment: You are not exactly conforming to the SO format. We have a very limited attention span to spare for each particular question, and we don't read multipage prose.

Comment: is it because you are using primitive types maybe? Try Integer instead of int, etc.

Comment: Well, the above example still fails even when the ONLY member of the RequObj class is a single String member variable. So, I have done something wrong with the WSDL probably, though I have IntelliJ creating it for me.

Comment: You shouldn't forget that Axis 1.4 also generates its specific server-config.wsdd file to configure all operations. Sometimes it generates it not the way you want. If you edit your question with your wsdl file and xsd schema, also .wsdd file I think I would be able to help.